# Rogue return appearing 9 characters into sendtext

Tags: c#, sendkeys, carriage-return

I'm getting a rogue carriage return 9 characters into my sendtext, but only on certain devices.

This program reads input that is presumably from a barcode scanner, and if necessary, eats that text, modifies it, and sends the modified text back to the focused window using sendkeys. It works fine on my PC. It works fine on my work PC. It will be used on Dell Latitude 7212 tablets though, and it does not work there. On those tablets only, I get a carriage return 9 characters into the text.

> - Verified that the input text that the sendkeys statement is using is identical on all machines. Input to sendkeys is identical on all machines.
> - Monitored the console output for the carriage return. Console output is identical in all devices. No carriage return is present between the characters.
> - Removed carriage return from sendkeys input for troubleshooting, since an additional return is added to the output. This did not impact the rogue carriage return in the tablets.
> - Verified that the code works on the .NET framework version in use on the tablets. It does. The tablets that are being used are imaged using the same image as our laptops, which work without any problem.

```
case 3:
    if ((Keys)vkCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        Globals.barcodeLength++;
        // set the barcode stage back to 0
        Globals.activeStage = 0;
        // set the barcode type back to 0
        Globals.barcodeType = 0;
        Globals.sendKeysActive = true;

        // format data for applicable program
        if (Globals.barcodeFormatStandard != "ProgramX")
        {
            switch (Globals.barcodeFormatStandard)
            {
               case "ProgramY":
                 SendKeys.Send(FormatForProgramY(Globals.barcodeDataString));
                 break;
               case "ProgramZ":

                 SendKeys.Send(FormatForProgramZ(Globals.barcodeDataString));
                 break;
             }
         }
         break;
}
```

Once we get into the sendkeys routine, the sendKeysActive boolean being set to true causes the program to allow the sent text to pass through without further processing:

```
if (Globals.sendKeysActive)
{
    if (Globals.barcodeLength == Globals.charactersTransmitted)
    {
        Globals.barcodeLength = 0;
        Globals.charactersTransmitted = 0;
        Globals.sendKeysActive = false;
        Globals.barcodeDataString = "";
    }
```

Once in this sequence, the program will fall back to the default text handling, where text is simply passed along to the active window (not absorbed as it is when I collect the barcode)

```
return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
```

Here's some example input:
']C1123456789'

Input to sendkeys is as follows:
'#123456789'

Sendkeys output matches the input on all but the tablets.

On the tablet, I receive the '#', followed by characters 1-8, then, on a new line, I receive the '9' character. Longer entries do not create subsequent line breaks. On the tablets, the first 9 characters are entered onto one line, and all subsequent characters remain on the second line.

In the console window that I currently have displaying, I am not able to detect this carriage return. Instead, I just see the output as I would expect it to be, but the output in the console does not match the output to the window.

Comment: Is it perhaps due to that other program/window running on the tablet, the one you are trying to send the keystrokes to? If not done already and if technically possible, use that very same program (same version) from the tablet on your PCs (i am not sure whether the laptops you mentioned are the PCs you are talking about) and see whether the effect/problem will be happening there too...

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've been running all of the text input into Notepad on all of these devices. Interesting (to me at least), I just tested this on an alternate tablet, and experienced the same issue with the 'rogue' return. For clarity,the PCs I'm talking about are the laptops. All of the laptops seem to behave as expected. The issue appears to be isolated to tablets.

Comment: Hmm, i have not really an idea. Are you sure the string you send via SendKeys does not contain some weird (invisible) control characters by accident that only trip the tablets? To verify `FormatForProgramZ` is not causing such issue, you could perhaps assign the string returned by `FormatForProgramZ` to a variable, display the string length and the string content in some fashion and check whether the string length matches the number of visible characters...

Comment: Appreciate your assistance. I just had the program write to a file, and both outputs are identical: #123456789123456789{ENTER}{ENTER}{ENTER}. Something I realize now that I failed to mention is that this sequence is driven by an {ENTER} keystroke. I will update the code above to reflect.

Comment: Okay, two further suggestions (that might or might not help): What if you don't send ENTER keys with together with the barcode data string, but rather send the {ENTER} key stroke(s) in a separate SendKeys call after a little delay (50ms...100ms perhaps)? Or, what about sending every character key separately with a little delay between each?